# Not able to get friends birthday

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

as per documentation on 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/user-data-ios-sdk/#step3

i am using following code to as for permission to get friends birthday

appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {

 NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_location",
                        @"user_birthday",
                        @"user_likes",
                        nil];

return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];
    }
```

and in view controller.m i am using folwoing code in view did load

```
     NSString *query =
     @"SELECT  uid, name, birthday, birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2      FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 25)";
    // Set up the query parameter
   NSDictionary *queryParam =
  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:query, @"q", nil];
   // Make the API request that uses FQL

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                          }
                      }];
```

but i am not able to get friend birthday date.. no request is sent to friend to access his birthday..

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add permission **friends_birthday** in your permission array like this :

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_location",
                        @"user_birthday",
                        @"user_likes",
                        @"friends_birthday",
                        nil];
```

it will work for you.